# Replace .unbind() with .off()

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.9. How can this be rewritten to replace `.unbind()` with `.off()`?

```
$span_rename_folder.children().children(':image.inplace_cancel').unbind('click').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$span_rename_folder
    .children()
    .children(':image.inplace_cancel')
    .off('click')
    .on('click', function(){...});
```

That will remove all click events from the selected element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I got an error when I ran your suggested code but it will work if I rewrite to this:     $span_rename_folder.children().children(':image.inplace_cancel').off('click').on('click', function(){

Comment: Sorry.  I misunderstood what you were looking for.  Didn't realize you still wanted the onclick at the end.  I updated my answer.