# Upgrade jQuery to 3.0: rewrite bind() to on() & unbind() to off()

Tags: jquery

`bind`() and `unbind`() were deprecated in jQuery 3.0.0.
[jQuery Upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-bind-and-delegate) says that API documentation explains how to rewrite them with `on()` & `off()`, but I can't find where it explains that.

We have lots of usages of deprecated methods in the app, but majority were upgraded just fine, but there are two cases where it is not clear:

1. Bind has boolean argument `preventBubble` argument and we pass false in some cases. How do I achieve same (`preventBubble=false`) with `on()`?
2. We have few usages on unbind where we call `unbind(eventName, functionHandler)`. `off()` needs selector as second argument in order to pass `functionHandler`. How do I rewrite that using `off()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to stop an event from bubbling.

Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault().

Or, probably more useful is to call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the event handler.

As to `.off()` you can pass only two arguments with the second being the handler function. JQ will assign appropriately and assign `undefined` to the selector argument. That may or may not work depending on how you specified `on`.

You might also want to look into namespacing events as it can simplify specifying  exactly which events you want to remove. For example (from the documentation)

```
// Delegate events under the ".validator" namespace
$( "form" ).on( "click.validator", "button", validate );

// Remove event handlers in the ".validator" namespace
$( "form" ).off( ".validator" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Selector as second argument is optional for setting a delegation target. Since this isn't how your `bind()` would be set up it isn't an issue

`bind()` uses `on()` internally, you should be able to simply rename `bind` to `on`

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that describes this, see [link](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/) and [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149701/replace-unbind-with-off)

> $span_rename_folder
>   .children()
>   .children(':image.inplace_cancel')
>   .off('click')
>   .on('click', function(){...});
>
> That will remove all click events from the selected element.